# a c program that output a combation of 3 numbers, stocked in an array

Tags: c

Trying to write a c programm that writes a combination of 3 set of numbers and avoid reputation, not very good in C language. Something is wrong with one of my condition

```
int ft_putchar(char c){
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void ft_print_comb(void){
    int numbers[3] = {48, 48, 48};

    while(numbers[0] <= 55){
        if((numbers[0] < numbers[1]) && (numbers[1] < numbers[2])){
            ft_putchar(numbers[0]);
            ft_putchar(numbers[1]);
            ft_putchar(numbers[2]);
            if(numbers[0] != 55){
                ft_putchar(',');
            }
            if(numbers[0] != 55){
                ft_putchar(' ');
            }
            if(numbers[2]++ >= 57){
                numbers[2] = 48;
                numbers[1]++;
            }
            if(numbers[1] >= 57){
                numbers[1] = 48;
                numbers[0]++;
            }
        }
    }       
 }

 int main(void){
     ft_print_comb();
 }
```

Comment: The `while` condition is true. The `if` condition is not. So how long will the while loop loop?

Comment: You should tell us what is the expected output and what do you get. Also this is a good time to start using a debugger. Step through your program and see what happens.

Comment: To make your program more readable, you should not use magic numbers. You can use `'0'` instead of `48` etc..

Comment: What do you mean by "Something is wrong"? What output are you expecting?

Comment: @Gerhardh@ "more readable" -> "portable".

Comment: What does repetition mean in this case? Is `123` same as `321` or different?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you create an infinite loop. Since all 3 numbers start out equal, the condition

```
if((numbers[0] < numbers[1]) && (numbers[1] < numbers[2]))
```

is false, so the body of the `if` never gets entered, `numbers[0]` never gets incremented, and `while(numbers[0] <= 55){` is always true.

You can get (what I think is) the desired output with nested for loops:

```
int numbers[3] = {'0', '0', '0'};
for (int i = numbers[0]; i <= '9'; i++) {
    for (int j = numbers[1]; j <= '9'; j++) {
        for (int k = numbers[2]; k <= '9'; k++) {
            if (i < j && j < k) {
                printf("%c%c%c, ", i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```